# Django Limiting Choices in a form after a selection

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I want to limit the choices given in a form after a selection of a previous field.
This is my models.py file:

```
class Course(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
course_id = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="")
major = models.CharField(
    max_length=45,
    choices= (
    ('bachelorcollege', 'Bachelor College'),
    ('appliedmathematics', 'Applied Mathematics'),
    ('appliedphysics', 'Applied Physics'),
    ('architecture', 'Architecture, Urbanism and Building Sciences'),
    ('automotive', 'Automotive'),
    ('biomedicalengineering', 'Biomedical Engineering'),
    ('chemicalengineering', 'Chemical Engineering'),
    ('computerscience', 'Computer Science'),
    ('electricalengineering', 'Electrical Engineering'),
    ('industrialdesign', 'Industrial Design'),
    ('industrialengineering', 'Industrial Engineering'),
    ('mechanicalengineering', 'Mechanical Engineering'),
    ('psychologyandtechnology', 'Psychology and Technology'),
    ('sustainableinnovation', 'Sustainable Innovation'),
    ),
    default='computerscience',
    )
def __str__(self):
    return self.name

def __major__(self):
    return self.major


class Resource(models.Model):
uploadedBy = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
resourcefile = models.FileField(blank=False, default="")
major = models.CharField(
    max_length=45,
    choices= (
    ('bachelorcollege', 'Bachelor College'),
    ('appliedmathematics', 'Applied Mathematics'),
    ('appliedphysics', 'Applied Physics'),
    ('architecture', 'Architecture, Urbanism and Building Sciences'),
    ('automotive', 'Automotive'),
    ('biomedicalengineering', 'Biomedical Engineering'),
    ('chemicalengineering', 'Chemical Engineering'),
    ('computerscience', 'Computer Science'),
    ('electricalengineering', 'Electrical Engineering'),
    ('industrialdesign', 'Industrial Design'),
    ('industrialengineering', 'Industrial Engineering'),
    ('mechanicalengineering', 'Mechanical Engineering'),
    ('psychologyandtechnology', 'Psychology and Technology'),
    ('sustainableinnovation', 'Sustainable Innovation'),
    ),
    #default='computerscience',
    )

course = models.ForeignKey(Course)
resourcetype = models.CharField(
    max_length=45,
    choices= (
    ('Summary', 'Summary'),
    ('Exam', 'Exam'),
    ),
    default='Summary',
    )
upload_date = models.DateTimeField(
        blank=True, null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

And this is my forms.py file:

```
class UploadForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Resource
    fields = ('title', 'major', 'course', 'resourcetype', 'resourcefile')


class AddCourseForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Course
    fields = ('name', 'course_id', 'major')
```

Now When I load the UploadForm in a template you can select a major, followed by a course. But when selecting a major, I want to limit the courses that belong to that major (I now get all the courses). So if I for example select biomedicalengineering, I want to limit the choices in courses to just the courses belonging to that major. Any comments on how I modelled the database are also welcome.

Background Info: I am trying to develop a website where users can upload summaries and exams (belonging to a particular course, which belongs to a particular major)

Comment: Selecting a major in a browser is a front end work, django form is defined in the backend and couldn't detect a user selects something thus couldn't apply any restrictions naturally. You need to use ajax to dynamically populate the subset of the courses.

Comment: I haven't used it, but https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects might be an option. Seems to implement the ajax stuff for you.

Comment: Thank you @ShangWang and AMG. I was well aware of the fact that django form is defined in the backend, but I thought maybe there was something implemented in django to apply it. Thank you AMG for the link . I implemented the django smart selects. Works like a charm!